# Why is Python ignoring these operations?

Tags: python, function, format

So in this piece of code

```
    for c, a in enumerate(final): 
      passed = check(a, start, (((c+1)*tries)*100/cap))
      if passed:
        filtered_final.append(a)
        print("[{}]".format((((c+1)*tries)*100)/cap) + " YOU LOST {} TIMES".format(a))
```

Pycharm won't throw up any error, it just keeps ignoring this part:

> *100/cap

Whatever I change or add it still ignores it and I get the same result.

As you may note I only mess around with coding for fun, I'm sure this is a silly problem.

Comment: nope, generally is bigger than 1000

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore"? What exactly does `check` do with is arguments?

Comment: `check` is kind of a filter

Comment: Show the output of `print` statement as well as the value of `c`, `tries` and `cap`

Comment: wanna hear something stupid? the reason why the output was the same was because pycharm was running a previous version of the code... smh all solved guys. I should delete the post right?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you provided insufficient data, so it's hard to help you. Please provide full context of variables and example of output you get.

If your main problem is just this snippet: `(((c+1)*tries)*100/cap)`, then it's rather straight forward and there is nothing that can fail unpredictably.

I assume `tries` and `cap` variables are some integers and `c` is integer in `range(len(final))`.

So to debug and check if your problem is caused by mentioned code snippet, you could just analyze smaller parts of your code - I will try with some random variables:

```
cap = 1000
tries = 5
final = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for c, a in enumerate(final):
    print((c + 1) * tries * 100 / cap)
```

This outputs:

```
0.5
1.0
1.5
2.0
2.5
```

Now let's remove `100/cap` that you mentioned is being ignored and see if the output changed:

```
cap = 1000
tries = 5
final = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for c, a in enumerate(final):
    print((c + 1) * tries)
```

This outputs:

```
5
10
15
20
25
```

So with taking smaller fragments of your code you could potentially exclude possibility that this is a faulty piece of your code. If your code does something that you didn't expect maybe faulty piece is somewhere else?

As I said, it's hard to tell for sure what's going wrong without proper context. However it seems to me that `*100/cap` part should work just fine.